# Javascript sort array of multiple values in one index

Tags: javascript, arrays, graph

I have an array with values

```
[[300, 2.6], [400, 2.2], [500, 3.0]]
```

How can I sort both dimensions such that I can display the output correctly in a graph?
`array.sort()` does not seem to work as it only sorts by one value in the entire array.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a valid js array. What are the elements? Is it: [[300,2.6], [400, 2.2], [500, 3.0]] ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is a combination of values from two arrays.

Comment: so you want to sort by the first element of each pair?

Comment: @user1610834 I've edited your post to make the code valid syntax. A multi-dimensional array has arrays within arrays, yours is invalid.

Comment: The `.sort()` method takes a callback function, which you can use to sort the array just how you like. Read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best shot is to use [lodash](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js):

```js
var values = [[500, 1.1], [300, 2.2], [400, 1.5]];

var sorted = _.sortBy(values, function(pair){return pair[0];});

console.log('sorted values: ' + JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ...why? Writing a vanilla Javascript sorting function is trivial, and doesn't have dependencies. Including an entire library just to sort an array is way overkill (unless you intend on using the library extensively).

Comment: That's an excellent point and I can understand where you are coming from, but as projects grow, the custom sorting, filtering, pickig and restructuring code clogs up the code. 
IMHO, lodash is an important library that belongs in most projects once they reach a certain size and worth knowing, learning and using. Using it on a daily basis, I guess the first place I look for a solution is there